# How Java Thread Class Determines Which thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

While Going through the java tutorial on sun site, I see following piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    heavyCrunch(inputs[i]);
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        //We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
        return;
    }
}
```

Since Thread.interrupted() is a static function, how does java knows which thread is calling it? 
eg. I expected it to be of type: this.interrupted() or Thread.interrupted(this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks at [`Thread.currentThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()).

---

If you want to know how *that* works, it's a native method, and probably JVM-specific so there's no quick answer.

Comment: Same question applies to this function call as well, since there can be multiple threads running at the same time on a multicore machine, how can jvm determine current thread?

Comment: See my update - the method is native and probably hooks straight into the JVM - it's not 'java' code anymore.

Comment: @sachin
The current thread is defined as the thread that actually called interrupted(). How many other threads are running and on which core is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.interrupted() will execute in the same thread as your loop, so that method will simply check whether the current thread has been interrupted.

Comment: not clear, since this flag instance variable how can a static function check it?